# PAGECURL ANIMATION SUBTYPE

Tags: iphone, animation, subtype

I know this has been asked a thousand times and people will say that the @pagecurl will get rejected.

I tried reasoning with the client but they insist they want to push the app with that function in and it will have a chance of not being rejected.

The problem is that if I try animation.subtype , the animation will not listen to it. I.e if I have the orientation mode in landscape, the page curl will start from some other position even if I try setting the animationsubtype.

Anyone knows what I can do about that ?

The code is below:

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
  [animation setDelegate:self];
  // animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;

  if(rotation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
   animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
  }else if(rotation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
   animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
  }else if(rotation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
   animation.subtype = ....
  }else if(rotation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){

   animation.subtype = ....
}

animation setDuration:0.35];
        [animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        animation.type = @"pageCurl";
```

The top 2 seems to work but I can't change it when the orientation is in landscape mode.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are methods of doing this without the private API, and I'm building one myself to allow me to use any UIView and not just a CALayer with the Page Curl effect. Your best bet is to use Leaves, or PageCurl from Github. They're pre-planned for use with images, PDFs, and simple graphics as well.